# How to reverse the content of a specific dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reverse

I have a pandas dataframe `df1 = {'A':['a','b','c','d','e'],'no.':[0,1,2,3,4]}, df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['A','no.'])` where I would like to reverse in place the content of the second column with the result being like that: `df2 = {'A':['a','b','c','d','e'],'no.':[4,3,2,1,0]} df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2,columns=['A','no.'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to numpy and then indexing for change order:

```
df1['no.'] = df1['no.'].to_numpy()[::-1]
print (df1)
   A  no.
0  a    4
1  b    3
2  c    2
3  d    1
4  e    0
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. M. df1['no.'] = df1['no.'].iloc[::-1].to_numpy() worked already, what is then the difference to the edited version (df1['no.'] = df1['no.'].to_numpy()[::-1])

Comment: @mati - I edit answer because simplier, `iloc` then is not necessary.